# Updating multiple list items within same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a default value take application, My view loads all my value with one editor. My controller is not getting any of the data from the view?

I want to be able to edit all my value at the same time? How can I do this

**Model Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Demo.Models.Admin
{
    public class MerchantPackageTransactionModel
    {
        public MerchantPackageTransactionModel()
        {
            FeatureList = new List<PackageFeatureModel>();
        }
        public int PackageId { get; set; }
        public string PackageName { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        public List<PackageFeatureModel> FeatureList { get; set; }
    }

    public class PackageFeatureModel
    {
        public int FeatureId { get; set; }
        public string FeatureName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View Code**

```
@model Demo.Models.Admin.MerchantPackageTransactionModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreatePackageTransaction";
    Layout = "~/Themes/green/Views/Shared/_AdminDashboard.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MerchantPackageTransactionModel</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PackageId)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackageName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PackageName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>

        @foreach (var item in Model.FeatureList)
        {

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.FeatureId)

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Feature Name")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FeatureName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Type")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Type)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Default Value")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DefaultValue)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Value")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Value)
            </div>
        }

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller code**

```
public ActionResult CreatePackageTransaction(MerchantPackageTransactionModel objMerchantPackageTransactionModel)
{
    foreach (var item in objMerchantPackageTransactionModel.FeatureList)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            GR.InsertOrUpdate(item);
        }
    }
    GR.Save();
    return View(objMerchantPackageTransactionModel);
}
```

Comment: I´m missing the HttpMethod used in your action. And when you submit your form it hits at the action? None of the values are coming fulfilled?

Comment: yes i put [HttpPost] in my code, but i didn't get PackageFeatureModel model list value at post method

Comment: I am trying  @Html.EditorFor,  Html.TextBoxFor,  Html.TextBox but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is, because you are using

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => item.Value)
```

that is a command directly associated with the model and it is being used to render an input not accessed from the model (item), it is rendering an input html with the "wrong" name:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="item_Value" name="item.Value" type="text" value="">
```

when it should be

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="FeatureList_0__Value" name="FeatureList[0].Value" type="text" value="">
```

And, as name does not match with the one from the model (FeatureList), the framework cannot do the automatic bind when the request hits the server.

You have a two options to fix it:

- Create the html by hand, setting the correct (expected) name; or:
- In the iteration use an index so that the EditorFor generates the input with the expected name:

  ```
  @{
      var index = 0;
  }

  @foreach (var item in Model.FeatureList)
  {

      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FeatureList[index].FeatureId)

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.Label("Feature Name")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FeatureList[index].FeatureName)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.Label("Type")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FeatureList[index].Type)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.Label("Default Value")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FeatureList[index].DefaultValue)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.Label("Value")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeatureList[index].Value)
      </div>

      index++;
  }
  ```

I have tested and it just work worked fine. Have a nice weekend! Regards.